# Many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework where join table has more than two fields?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I am importing a database into Entity Framework and I'm having trouble with a many-to-many relationship that looks like this:
[image]

My understanding is that if the "join table" (the middle one) contains only two fields (the foreign keys) then EF will automatically remove the middle table and create a many-to-many relationship. Unfortunately I don't have control over the database schema, so does anyone know if there's a way to replicate that behaviour manually?

For the record, there is no purpose behind that Id field in Employee_Employee_Type, it's just poorly designed.

Comment: You can try by removing Id from association table on your sandbox, update diagram from database, and then restore Id. Not sure if it will work correctly, but it is worth trying.

Comment: Probably a viable solution, but a big pain if I need to regenerate from DB again later on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Entity Framework 4 recipes, page 554, this is how you'd do it (it's not pretty).

Essentially, you want to create a View of the Employee_Employee_type mapping table, but without the extra column, then manually map it to the other two tables.  Below are pics of the relevant pages.  I think (and hope!) this is covered by academic free-use copyright laws...

The book is fantastic, BTW, so I'd recommend buying it.  Hopefully that will endear me to the author if he happens upon this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks like that's the best solution, even though it's pretty darn ugly. My boss actually picked that book up for me but another dev is reading it at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

yeah that is probably the best approach to give you cleaner experience on querying and for the inserting and updating you can always use the link table.
Eventually, will not mention when, EF will support navigation properties with payload. 
I am glad people like the work. It honestly took 1 year to write the book.